# Approximation scheme for Multiple Choice Knapsack

Tags: algorithms, approximation, knapsack-problems

The paper _Fast Approximation Algorithms for Knapsack Problems (E. Lawler, 1979) gives an [FPTAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme#Deterministic) (fully polynomial time approximation scheme) for the multiple choice knapsack problem (MKP). But MKP is strongly NP-hard, so it cannot have an FPTAS unless P=NP. Is the result of this paper wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The paper you cite is not available to me. However, according to [this paper: "Improved Fully Polynomial time Approximation Scheme for the 0-1
Multiple-choice Knapsack Problem"](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mukul/01MCKP.pdf),

> 0-1 MCKP is $\text{NP}$-hard [4] as it contains the 0-1 Knapsack problem as a special case [5, 13] but *it can be solved in pseudo-polynomial time* (emphasis added) through dynamic programming [7, 2].

Thus, 0-1 MCKP is not strongly $\text{NP}$-hard.

One of the citations is

[7] K. Dudzinski, S. Walukiewicz, “Exact Methods for the Knapsack Problem and its Generalizations”, European Journal of Operational Research, (28), (1987): 3–21.